# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Proof Assistants has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Eric]

[image: Trebor]

[image: Couchy]

They will be [your initial pro-tem moderator team](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6675471908470784).

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, pro-tem moderators! Your willingness to support the site is appreciated.